# Making Fill Plot Matplotlib - Error: invalid type promotion

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I am trying to create a fill plot using Matplotlib in Python (I am using spyder IDE) using the code below. However, I receive the error posted at the bottom of the code. The dataframe I want to plot contains dates along the x-axis and then a range of y-values (I created the sample dataframe to see if the error was reproduced, in case there was a problem with my dataframe).

This seems to be snagging me quite a bit and I am trying to start from scratch (and visited the matplotlib website, which is posted in the comments within the codes).

I am very new to Python and Matplotlib and maybe I am just missing something basic. I will bee needing to add a lot of plots with date-time x-axis for the work I am performing, so if there are any additional features I should be aware of, please let me know as it would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = [{'a':dt.datetime(2015,1,1,12,0,0), 'b':1},{'a':dt.datetime(2015,1,1,13,0,0), 'b':2},{'a':dt.datetime(2015,1,1,14,0,0), 'b':3}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = [{'a':dt.datetime(2015,1,1,12,0,0), 'c':9},{'a':dt.datetime(2015,1,1,13,0,0), 'c':8},{'a':dt.datetime(2015,1,1,14,0,0), 'c':7}]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', on = 'a')

plt.fill(df3['a'], df3['c'])
plt.show()

"""
used this example code from Fill Demo on page http://matplotlib.org/users/screenshots.html
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(0, 1)
y = np.sin(4 * np.pi * x) * np.exp(-5 * x)

plt.fill(x, y, 'r')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
"""

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 280, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)

TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

Comment: Works for me. What versions of pandas, matplolib, nad NumPy do you use?

Comment: Pandas 0.17.1, Matplotlib 1.5.0 and Numpy 1.10.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the values instead of the Series directly:

```
plt.fill(df3['a'].values, df3['c'].values
```

You more likely want this type of plot:

```
plt.fill_between(df3['a'].values, df3['c'].values)
```

Comment: Works! I did not want to include the 'c' values as I was just merging dataframes to include single columns. The only way I was able to get it to work was pd.merge with on ='a' because the column names had to be the same. Otherwise the time column would be brought over as well. Is there a way to pd.merge and specify the columns by name, then just merge those specific columns (when column names are different)? I can ask a new question if required...

Comment: @Prevost Better ask a new question and provide example data along with your explanation.

Comment: Does plotting the Series value remove my ability to format the x-axis based on a certain time range? This example is small, but when I have data spanning across multiple days am I able to set the x-axis span using datetime formats? I am migrating from Excel, so I am thinking that they have been converted to text values...

Comment: No. `values`  is a NumPy array with Datetime entries.